# Best possible match between strings

Tags: c#, regex

I had a problem finding solution to match the string so we can get possible match if there is any.

Working with the string which contains `username` like below,

```
    string email = "johndoe@smo.co";
    string username = "johndoe";
    //username could be john.doe or johnd
```

Matching username with the `fullRes` string to find if user exist in string

```
string fullRes = "John Doey\nMr.Django P\nSharif Khan";
string[] wrds = fullRes.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n"},StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Now with respect to `wrds`, i have used `.contains` but its not going to work.

```
foreach(var s in wrds){
    string[] w = s.Split();
    bool isPossibleMatchName1 = username.contains(w[0]);
    bool isPossibleMatchName2 = username.contains(w[1]);
}

//given method will work on 
//string fullRes = "john doe\nMr.Django P\nSharif Khan";
```

I was trying to find the solution where i can find the possible match.

If someone can help i will be very thankful.

Comment: Search for the `Levenshtein` algorithm online. It's relatively easy to implement and yields good results to find a best possible match with either wrong or missing characters

Comment: Try `wrds.Any(x => string.Concat(x.Where(Char.IsLetter)).ToLower().Contains(username) )`, see [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/F1mE3j). Or with letter-only `username` check, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/16l5my): `wrds.Any(x => string.Concat(x.Where(Char.IsLetter)).ToLower().Contains(string.Concat(username.Where(Char.IsLetter)).ToLower()) )`

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop thanks for the reply. yes sure.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the valuable help, i will integrate  and feedback.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162091/detect-differences-between-two-strings

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks for the link, i have somewhat reached the solution.