# diff between 2 strings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am solving a problem on one of the online platforms where the question is on finding the diff between 2 string.

Question: Given two strings of uppercase letters source and target, list (in string form) a sequence of edits to convert from source to target that uses the least edits possible.

For example, with strings source = "ABCDEFG", and target = "ABDFFGH" we might return: ["A", "B", "-C", "D", "-E", "F", "+F", "G", "+H"

Here is what I tried:

```
function diffBetweenTwoStrings(source, target) {
  console.log(source);
  console.log(target);
  let output = [],
    result = getCompareMap(source, target);

  buildTheResult(result, source, target);

  console.log(result);

  constructOutput(source, target, result, output)

  return output;
}

function buildTheResult(result, source, target) {
  for (let row = 0; row < target.length; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < source.length; col++) {
      if (source[col] === target[row]) {
        result[row + 1][col + 1] = result[row][col];
      } else {
        result[row + 1][col + 1] = Math.min(result[row + 1][col], result[row][col + 1]) + 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

function constructOutput(source, target, result, output) {
  let rows = target.length,
    cols = source.length;

  while (cols > 0 && rows > 0) {
    // console.log(`source: ${source[cols-1]} target: ${target[rows-1]} result col+1: ${result[rows][cols]} row+1: ${result[rows][cols]}`);
    if ((source[cols - 1] === target[rows - 1]) && ((result[rows - 1][cols - 1] <= result[rows - 1][cols]) && (result[rows - 1][cols - 1] <= result[rows][cols - 1]))) {
      //&& (result[rows - 1][cols - 1] <= result[rows - 1][cols])) {
      output.unshift(source[cols - 1]);
      // console.log("diagonal up with " + source[cols - 1]);
      rows--;
      cols--;
    } else if (result[rows - 1][cols] <= result[rows][cols - 1]) {
      output.unshift("+" + target[rows - 1]);
      // console.log("moving up with " + target[rows - 1]);
      rows--;
    } else if (result[rows][cols - 1] <= result[rows - 1][cols]) {
      output.unshift("-" + source[cols - 1]);
      // console.log("moving left with " + source[cols - 1]);
      cols--;
    }
  }

  while (rows > 0) {
    if (result[rows - 1][cols] <= result[rows][cols]) {
      output.unshift("+" + target[rows - 1]);
    } else {
      output.unshift(target[rows - 1]);
    }
    rows--;
  }

  while (cols > 0) {
    if (result[rows][cols - 1] <= result[rows][cols]) {
      output.unshift("-" + source[cols - 1]);
    } else {
      output.unshift(source[cols - 1]);
    }
    cols--;
  }
}

function getCompareMap(source, target) {
  let i, compareMap = [...Array(target.length + 1)].map(x => Array(source.length + 1).fill(0));

  for (i = 0; i <= target.length; i++) {
    compareMap[i][0] = i;
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= source.length; i++) {
    compareMap[0][i] = i;
  }

  return compareMap;
}

// O(n^2)
let source = 'GMMGZGGLUGUH',
  target = 'HPGPPMGLLUUU';

console.log(diffBetweenTwoStrings(source, target));

// expect => ["+H","+P","G","-M","+P","+P","M","G","-Z","-G","-G","L","+L","U","-G","U","-H","+U"]
// actual => ["+H","+P","G","+P","+P","M","-M","G","-Z","-G","-G","L","+L","U","-G","U","-H","+U" ]
```

It works for 6 cases and fails for 2(total 8 cases).

The other case it fails for is:

```
source = "AABACC"
target = "BABCAC"

// Expected => ["-A","-A","B","A","+B","C","+A","C"]
// Actual =>   ["+B","A","-A","B","+C","A","C","-C"]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162091/detect-differences-between-two-strings/52255452#52255452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this](https://gist.github.com/yubuylov/b37608440af27c0e8e253d4aacc6137a) is the original question, it includes the following proviso:

> If there are multiple answers, use the answer that favors removing from the source first.

Your answer doesn't satisfy this criterion.

Comment: This is it `"If there are multiple answers, use the answer that favors removing from the source first."` Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're "missing" that your actual results are another valid difference.  Both edit lists are 8 elements long, with four matches, two deletions, and two insertions.  Unless there is some particular criterion that you haven't listed, the two answers are equally correct.