# What is C# full analog PHP function "similar_text()"?

Tags: c#, algorithm, similarity

What is **C#** full analog **PHP** function `similar_text()` ?

I tried this code

```
int ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string source, string target)
{
    if ((source == null) || (target == null)) return 0;
    if ((source.Length == 0) || (target.Length == 0)) return 0;
    if (source == target) return source.Length;

    int sourceWordCount = source.Length;
    int targetWordCount = target.Length;

    // Step 1
    if (sourceWordCount == 0)
        return targetWordCount;

    if (targetWordCount == 0)
        return sourceWordCount;

    int[,] distance = new int[sourceWordCount + 1, targetWordCount + 1];

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= sourceWordCount; distance[i, 0] = i++) ;
    for (int j = 0; j <= targetWordCount; distance[0, j] = j++) ;

    for (int i = 1; i <= sourceWordCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= targetWordCount; j++)
        {
            // Step 3
            int cost = (target[j - 1] == source[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

            // Step 4
            distance[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(distance[i - 1, j] + 1, distance[i, j - 1] + 1), distance[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }

    return distance[sourceWordCount, targetWordCount];
}

double CalculateSimilarity(string source, string target)
{
    if ((source == null) || (target == null)) return 0.0;
    if ((source.Length == 0) || (target.Length == 0)) return 0.0;
    if (source == target) return 1.0;

    int stepsToSame = ComputeLevenshteinDistance(source, target);
    return (1.0 - ((double)stepsToSame / (double)Math.Max(source.Length, target.Length)));
}
```

Result value are not equivalent php.

[PHP Similar_text() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php): This calculates the *similarity* between two `string`s as described in

> Programming Classics: Implementing the World's Best Algorithms by
>   Oliver
>
> (ISBN 0-131-00413-1).

Note that this implementation does not use a stack as in Oliver's pseudo code, but *recursive calls* which may or may not speed up the whole process. Note also that the complexity of this algorithm is `O(N**3)` where `N` is the length of the longest string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162091/detect-differences-between-two-strings/52255452#52255452

Comment: How to get an integer value, not sequence?

Comment: All you have to do remove back trace from `EditSequence`. Please, see my answer

Comment: there are different implementations of the soundex algorithm for C#. The original soundex algorithm does work best for english text but doesn't account enough for international character sets. So maybe you'd like to research and reuse already existing solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to implement *edit distance*, say, Levenstein one; let's do it as more *generic* as we can:

See [Detect differences between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162091/detect-differences-between-two-strings/52255452#52255452)

for *edit sequence* and more details.

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static double EditDistance<T>(IEnumerable<T> from,
                                      IEnumerable<T> to,
                                      Func<T, double> insertCost,
                                      Func<T, double> deleteCost,
                                      Func<T, T, double> editCost) {
  T[] source = from.ToArray();
  T[] target = to.ToArray();

  // Minimum cost so far
  double[][] D = Enumerable
    .Range(0, source.Length + 1)
    .Select(line => new double[target.Length + 1])
    .ToArray();

  // Edge: all removes
  double sum = 0.0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= source.Length; ++i)
    D[i][0] = (sum += deleteCost(source[i - 1]));

  // Edge: all inserts
  sum = 0.0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= target.Length; ++i)
    D[0][i] = (sum += insertCost(target[i - 1]));

  // Having fit N - 1, K - 1 characters let's fit N, K
  for (int i = 1; i <= source.Length; ++i)
    for (int j = 1; j <= target.Length; ++j) {
      // here we choose the operation with the least cost
      double insert = D[i][j - 1] + insertCost(target[j - 1]);
      double delete = D[i - 1][j] + deleteCost(source[i - 1]);
      double edit   = D[i - 1][j - 1] + editCost(source[i - 1], target[j - 1]);

      D[i][j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(insert, delete), edit);
    }

  return D[source.Length][target.Length];
}
```

Now it's easy to write `Similar_text`

**Routine:**

```
public static double Similar_text(string left, string right) {
  left = left ?? "";
  right = right ?? "";

  return left.Equals(right)
    ? 1.0
    : 1.0 - EditDistance(left, right, 
              insert => 1.0, 
              delete => 1.0, 
          (from, to) => from == to ? 0.0 : 2.0) 
      / Math.Max(left.Length, right.Length);
}
```

Time complexity is `O(left.Length * right.Length)` or `O(N**2)` if both strings have roughly equal lengths (`N`)

Comment: using System.Linq;
and  EditOperationKind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162091/detect-differences-between-two-strings/52255452#52255452

Comment: @Igor: We can get rid of `EditOperationKind` (if we don't want edit sequence); I've edited the answer