# How to mark the differences between two strings

Tags: string, algorithm

I want a function that would visually mark the differences between two strings.

Example 1:

*Input:*

- **Stack Overflow**
- **Stack overflowing**

*Output:*

- **Stack [O]verflow**
- **Stack [o]verflow[ing]**

Example 2:

*Input:*

- **Restack Overflow**
- **Stack-Ooooverflow**

*Output:*

- **[Res]tack[ ]Overflow**
- **[S]tack[-]O[ooo]verflow**

I've searched for this a lot, but I always end up with file compare functions. I want to visualise the difference between strings. One example I found is https://text-compare.com (this is exactly what I need), but it appears to use server-side code.

Language doesn't matter much, JavaScript, Python, but any pointers how to approach this problem would be nice.

I'm not necessarily looking for an implementation; I'd rather have some links to some website, since this is not an elementary problem. Not too difficult either, but you want to get it right.

Comment: [Edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) ?

Comment: Edit *sequence*? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162091/detect-differences-between-two-strings/52255452#52255452

Comment: Hmm, edit distance and sequence are interesting, but I'm not sure how to use them for this problem.

Comment: How far does the solution need to go? What would happen if you compared _stack overflow_ with _the stack is overflowing_, which bits would be highlighted? I'd imagine you'd want `[the] stack [is] overflow[ing]`, but this becomes infinitely more complicated when compared to `the flow stack is overflowing` - The word flow is in there twice (once as a difference, once as an equal) but both would be highlighted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be solved by finding the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) (LCS) of the two strings, then putting the square brackets around only those parts which are not part of the LCS.

For example, the LCS of `Stack Overflow` and `Stack ooverflowing` is `Stack verflow`, so the first string would be rendered as `Stack [O]verflow` and the second as `Stack [oo]verflow[ing]`, because those are the parts not present in the LCS.

There is a [standard dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Code_for_the_dynamic_programming_solution) for computing the LCS which is described on Wikipedia, and various [optimisations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Code_optimization) to this algorithm which speed it up in practical cases. The parts of each string which are not present in the LCS can be found by a simple loop maintaining the current index in the string and another index for the current position in the LCS.