# Anyone have method to find best match of string in list of strings in C#?

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to implement some kind of a *simplest spell checker* to find out and correct simple typos. I am looking for a method that can help me to find the *nearest string* to my string in C# if possible!

**For example**:

```
string source = "gnail"; // simple typo: 'n' instead of 'm'

List<string> KnownWords = new List<string> {
  "orange", 
  "gmail",    // <- the best fit for source: just one (edit) letter away
  "hotmail",  // <- drop two letters, edit one leeter
  "live", 
  "outlook"
};
```

**Expected result:**

```
"gmail"
```

The output should be `"gmail"` since `"gmail"` is just *one letter away* (one edit away) from `source` (`"gnail"`)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? what is expected output if input string is "nail" is it hotmail or gmail?

Comment: You can compute *edit distance* from `s` to all the other words in `L` and take the word with the *shortest* distance as an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162091/detect-differences-between-two-strings/52255452#52255452

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect differences between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162091/detect-differences-between-two-strings)

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar You are right, but in this case he should count the number of caracters also to find out that "gmail" is nearest !

Comment: @DmitryBychenko OK i will check that, Thank you :)

Comment: Are you implementing spellcheck?

Answer (score 0):

```
string source = "gnail"; // simple typo: 'n' instead of 'm'

List<string> KnownWords = new List<string> {
  "orange", 
  "gmail",    // <- the best fit for source: just one (edit) letter away
  "hotmail",  // <- drop two letters, edit one leeter
  "live", 
  "outlook"
};

private static string spellChecker(string toCheck)
        {
            List<string> updatedList = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                updatedList = KnownWords.FindAll(x => x.Length == toCheck.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine($"Could not find any match : {e.Message}");
                return "No Match Found";
            }

            int[] matches = new int[updatedList.Count];
            int matchedElements = 0, index = 0;

            foreach (string str in updatedList)
            {
                matchedElements = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < toCheck.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(str[i] == toCheck[i])
                    {
                        matchedElements++;
                    }
                }

                matches[index] = matchedElements;
                index++;
            }

            string toReturn = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                toReturn = updatedList[matches.ToList().IndexOf(matches.Max())];
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine($"No Elements matches the length of given words in the list : {ex.Message}");
            }

            return toReturn == string.Empty ? "Error Output" : toReturn;
        }
```

This might be too long but this works the best when the given word is as the same length of any of the string in the known words list.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this one :)